# How can I fix this simple mean calculator so it works and how can I make it so it takes as many numbers as I want?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a mean calculator with HTML, JS, and Jquery. I wasn't sure how to retrieve the number of numbers that are entered so I came up with `var numberOfNumbers = $('input').attr('class').length` but I don't think it works. What is a better way to collect the number of numbers used to find the mean? Is there anything else wrong with my code? Also how can I make it so that I can enter as many numbers as I want and find the average of them? Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Find Average</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="meancalculator.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Number 1</p>
    <input type="text" id="number1" class="numbers">
    <p>Number 2</p>
    <input type="text" id="number2" class="numbers">
    <p>Number 3</p>
    <input type="text" id="number3" class="numbers">
    <button>Calculate</button>
    <p>The mean is <span></span></p>
  </body>
</html>

$(function () {
  $('button').click(calculate)
})

var number1 = $('#number1').val()
var number2 = $('#number2').val()
var number3 = $('#number3').val()
var numberOfNumbers = $('input').attr('class').length

function calculate() {
  var result = (number1 + number2 + number3) / numberOfNumbers
}

$('span').html(result)
```

Comment: you mean a count of characters of all numbers entered at input ?

Comment: I mean the number that you divide the total by in order to find the average.

Answer (score 0):

Best case;

You can use "numbers" class for find it.

```
    var numberOfNumbers = $.find('.numbers').length;
```

Worst case;

If you think you will use "number" class for something else, you can add an data attribute for numbers such as;

```
<input type="text" id="number1" class="numbers" data-bla-bla="numbers">
```

and find specified data attribute;

```
var numberOfNumbers = 0;
$.each($.find('.numbers'),function(a,b) { if ($(b).attr('data-bla-bla') != undefined && $(b).attr('data-bla-bla') == 'numbers') { numberOfNumbers++; } });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('input').each()` for get `inputs` in the page and `$(e).val()` to get value of each element withing the `each()`

**DEMO**

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(calculate)
})

function calculate() {
  let result = 0
  $('input').each((i, e) => {
    let val = parseInt($(e).val());
    if (!isNaN(val)) {
      result += val
    }
  })
  $('span').html(result / $('input').length);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<p>Number 1</p>
<input type="text" id="number1" class="numbers">
<p>Number 2</p>
<input type="text" id="number2" class="numbers">
<p>Number 3</p>
<input type="text" id="number3" class="numbers">
<button>Calculate</button>
<p>The mean is <span></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your following code :

```
var numberOfNumbers = $('input').attr('class').length
```

to:

```
var numberOfNumbers = $('.numbers').length
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

- You are taking input field values outside of `calculate` function. By that time numbers may not have entered. Same goes for displaying results. Move these lines inside `calculate` function.
- Use `$('input.numbers').length` to get count of `input` elements having class `numbers`
- Read the numeric values with `+` in prefix as `+$('#number1').val()`

Here is your modified code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Find Average</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="meancalculator.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Number 1</p>
    <input type="text" id="number1" class="numbers">
    <p>Number 2</p>
    <input type="text" id="number2" class="numbers">
    <p>Number 3</p>
    <input type="text" id="number3" class="numbers">
    <button>Calculate</button>
    <p>The mean is <span></span></p>
</body>

</html>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('button').click(calculate)
    })


    function calculate() {
        var number1 = +$('#number1').val()
        var number2 = +$('#number2').val()
        var number3 = +$('#number3').val()
        var numberOfNumbers = $('input.numbers').length

        var result = (number1 + number2 + number3) / numberOfNumbers
        $('span').html(result)
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach the problem is just to have one input into which the user can add a list of numbers to take the mean of:

```js
$(function () {
  $('button').click(calculate)
})

var number1 = $('#number1').val()
var number2 = $('#number2').val()
var number3 = $('#number3').val()
var numberOfNumbers = $('input').attr('class').length

function calculate() {
  let numbers = $('#numbers').val().split(/[ ,]+/);
  let sum = numbers.reduce((c, v) => c + parseInt(v), 0);
  let result = sum / numbers.length;
  $('span').html(result);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Enter a list of numbers separated by space or comma:</p>
    <input type="text" id="numbers" class="numbers">
    <button>Calculate</button>
    <p>The mean is <span></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something dynamic like this :)

```js
var count = 1,
  total = 0,
  mean = 0;

$(document).on('click', '#addNewField', function() {
  var containerDiv = document.createElement('div');
  containerDiv.className += "inputWrapper";

  var inputField = document.createElement('input');
  inputField.setAttribute('type', 'number');
  inputField.className += 'number';

  containerDiv.append(inputField);

  var deleteSpan = document.createElement('span');
  deleteSpan.className += 'delete';

  inputField.after(deleteSpan);

  $('#fields').append(containerDiv);
  inputField.focus();

  count++;
  $('#count').text(count);
});

$(document).on('keyup', '.number', function() {
  calculate();
});

function calculate() {
  total = 0;
  mean = 0;

  $('.number').each(function() {
    total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    mean = total / count;
  });


  $('#total').text(total);
  $('#mean').text(mean);
}

$(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
  count--;
  $('#count').text(count);
  calculate();
});
```

```css
.inputWrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.number {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  display: block;
}

table td {
  text-align: center;
}

input.number+*:after {
  content: "×";
  font-size: 32px;
  top: 0;
  left: 5px;
  position: absolute;
}

#addNewField {
  height: 30px;
  width: 235px;
  margin: 10px 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="fields">
  <div class="inputWrapper">
    <input type="number" class="number"><span class='delete'></span>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="addNewField">+ Add New Field</button>

<table border="1px" cellPadding="10px">
  <tr>
    <th>Count</th>
    <th>Total</th>
    <th>Mean</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="count">1</td>
    <td id="total">0</td>
    <td id="mean">0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```